# Что такое "стечение знаков"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Тире ставится вместо двоеточия при счтении знаков препинания".

Answer (score 1):

Стечение.

Обычно под стечением понимают два знака рядом, если они ставятся по разным мотивам. Типичный случай - запятая и тире. Например, запятая закрывает обособленный оборот или в первой части ССП предложение, а тире присоединяет вторую.

Знаки, ставящиеся рядом по одной причине (при оформлении прямой речи, например), обычно трактуются как единый знак и не являются стечением.

Answer (score 0):

"Счтение" - обычная опечатка, в шапке вопроса я её исправила. Речь о ***стечении знаков препинания***.

Стечение знаков - это когда их больше одного.

Но тире или двоеточие - это за рамками вопроса; сейчас говорится об "агрессивности" тире: оно всё чаще на практике заменяет традиционное двоеточие.

Comment: А схематически это стечение можно как-нибудь изобразить?

Comment: Стечение знаков - запросто: *"Ах вот ты как?!." - мстительно процедила бывшая жена.* Стеклись пять знаков: вопрос, восклик, точка, кавычка, тире.